# dockerizing microservice native image throws java security exception

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to create a sample microservice to fetch the data from an external source using smallrye rest client and resteasy jsonb extensions. runner.jar from the host machine works fine and the data is being retrieved from the source. But as soon as I build the native docker image, the problems begin. I get below error:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1903) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1402) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
```

I tried setting up `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustAnchors` variables by passing in ENTRYPOINT as well as create a custom docker image to add graalvm distribution as below Dockerfile:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal ADD graalvm-ce-linux-amd64-19.0.0.tar.gz / RUN chmod 775 /graalvm-ce-19.0.0 ENV PATH /graalvm-ce-19.0.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin WORKDIR /work/ COPY target/*-runner /work/application RUN chmod 775 /work EXPOSE 8080 ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c","./application -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/graalvm-ce-19.0.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustAnchors=/graalvm-ce-19.0.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts -Djava.library.path=/graalvm-ce-19.0.0/jre/lib/amd64 -Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried the suggestions at https://quarkus.io/guides/native-and-ssl-guide?

Comment: Yes. It seems Quarkus only works with graalvm-ce-1.0.0-rc16 as of now. It's still not upgraded to use newwer version.

Comment: That is correct for the current release, however it should be work with GraaVM 19.x soon